# Automated Flash Testing with C#

Tags: c#, flash, testing, automation

I am trying to write some software for automated testing of flash contained within webpages.

Specifically I am looking for assistance with 'hooking' onto a webpage which is running the flash and gaining access to the controls and events it uses so that I can simulate button clicks and then listen for the responses it produces.

Since it could be any flash movie running, I need to be able to gain access to the controls so I can try and make an educated guess as to which ones I need to simulate clicking.

I need it to be free or perhaps open source hopefully with examples ideally in a .net technology.

Can anyone offer assistance or examples, please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is Ruby library called [FlashWatir](http://code.google.com/p/flash-watir/). Not exactly what you were looking for, but close.

Answer (score 0):

First, Flash pages can be manipulated with JavaScript. For a reference on this see: http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_06.html

You can write something in C# or use Selenium (open source) to test the whole thing with some scripting. Selenium Remote Control has support for DotNet.

Selenium Remote Control
http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

Tutorial on using Selenium to test Flash:
http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Testing+Flash+with+Selenium+RC

Hope this helps.